# open source twitter?

Tags: open-source, twitter

I want to add twitter like function to my site, like t.mysite.com. Any open source, stable and easy to setup/use twitter software?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: just out of curiosity, why not just use twitter?  If you wanted a limited amount of people to see the posts, make the accounts private.  There are plenty of free APIs to access twitter functionality.

Comment: I want to keep all application on my site. For various reasons, like easy to manage, performance and control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check out StatusNet. It's an Open Source solution, that provides a similar functionality as Twitter.

http://status.net/

Answer (score 3):

There's twitter, they have an API and widget. And there are sites like wibya.com

Comment: Sorry, I did not make myself understood. What I mean is twitter like open source application, which I can easily integrate into my web site.